# Using a Bluetooth module to communicate with a Smartphone or Tab

Tags: module, bluetooth, msp430

I am currently trying to build a home automation system that can be controlled by a smartphone using Bluetooth technology. I will be using a MSP430 from TI to receive the commands that will be sent from the smartphone. My main doubts are on the way Bluetooth must be used.
I have read in some posts about the micro controller needing a bluetooth stack for using Bluetooth but on the other hand if you are using a Module such as a RN-42 or HC-06 there is no need for any software programming for this other than the physical connection itself. I am thinking of using a CC2560 as the bluetooth module.So can anyone point me in the right direction as to whether I need to program the MSP for Bluetooth stack or just physically connect the MSP to the module?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches you can take. Choose one that fits your background better.

1) Use a pre-built module that already includes the Bluetooth stack. These modules (such as the [Roving Networks RN-41](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12579)) provide a simple serial (UART) interface. Roving Networks also defined a simple command interface so the MCU (MSP430) can communicate with the module. No RF experience or Bluetooth experience is required, but you are at the mercy of the pre-defined interface.

**This method is strongly recommended for beginners.**

2) Build your own module based off TI's CC2560 chip. They provide a reference design, but you would need to get the module certified (expensive)! You would also need to write the Bluetooth stack yourself based on the specification as the chip may not be pre-flashed with any software.

**This method is really not a good option. Why reinvent the wheel? Modules with the Bluetooth stack already exist for you to use off-the-shelf.**

My suggestion is to go with choice 1. Wire your MSP430 UART lines to the RN-41 and write your UART driver (or use someone else's) and go! Good luck.

.